# Window Phone 8 Emulator not starting from visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

I've just installed the WP8 SDK, but when I try loading a project I created from Visual Studio it just starts the XDE and displays:

> Window Phone OS is starting up

But after about 4 minutes it shuts down.

However, when I start up of the emulator manually, it starts perfectly fine. Any idea what the problem could be ?

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you upgrade your system (windows Update) and modify the drivers on your network configuration. Just use the repair function of the WP8 SDK installation disc.